# Unique membership FIFO container

Tags: c++, containers, std

I need a first-in first-out queue which holds IDs with the catch that an ID should only be added if it is not already in the queue.

The best way I can think of is this:

```
typedef unsigned ID;
struct UniqueFifo
{
private:
   std::set<ID> ids; // keep track of what is already in
   std::queue<ID> fifo; // keep in fifo order
public:
   void push(ID x) {
       // only add to queue if not already in it
       if(ids.find(x) == ids.end()) {
           fifo.push(x);
           ids.insert(x);
       }
   }
   ID pop() {
       // pop from queue
       ID x = fifo.front();
       fifo.pop();
       // and also remove from map
       ids.erase(x);
       return x;
   }
};
```

Is there are more elegant way of doing this with C++ STL containers?

Comment: Do you have an estimation of the largest amount of elements the queue will hold?

Comment: Will a `set` keep it fifo? Or have you done magic with the IDs I'm missing?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Lets say 5000.

Comment: @doctorlove: I thought a set would order IDs by value no matter in which order I add them.

Comment: @doctorlove No. `set` keep it ordered according to `Comparator` (defaut `<`)

Comment: So, something issues the IDs in the order in which you try to insert things? Fair enough.

Comment: ID is completely unrelated to the order in which I add them to the queue. It may also be a pointer to something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a second data structure like that, optimised for insertion and searching, is the most scalable solution; but if the queue never gets particularly large, then it might be more efficient (and certainly simpler) to do a linear search in the queue itself. You'll need `deque` itself, rather then the `queue` adapter, in order to access the contents.

If it is large enough to justify a searchable "index", then consider using `unordered_set` if available, or some other hash-based set if not; that's likely to be faster, if you only require uniqueness and not any particular ordering.

Your code needs to insert the ID into the set as well as the queue. Conveniently, you can combine this with the check for uniqueness, so that only a single search is needed:

```
if (ids.insert(x).second) {
    fifo.push(x);
}
```

You might also consider storing set iterators, rather than values, in the queue, to make erasing more efficient.

Comment: Note: probably best answer so far, though I would take the opportunity to mention Boost.MultiIndex (even if it might be seen as overkill) or perhaps Boost.Bimap.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is not bad, but you need to use a `std::set<ID>`, not a `std::map`(a map is used to map keys to values while you only care about values here). Also consider using `std::unordered_set` if `c++11` is available.

Answer (score 2):

It's not bad at all. I can see other way to do this, mostly using one container (because the only "problem" that I see is that you're using 2 containers and so have to assert all the time that they are consistent with each other), but they are not more elegant and maybe cost even more.

IMHO leep this design (at least this interface) using a `std::unordered_set` instead of a `std::set` until you can benchmark your performances. After that you may have no problem or maybe the extra lookup in `std::set` will be too high for you. In this case you may try to keep a `std::queue<std::pair<ID, std::unordered_set<ID>::const_iterator>>` to ease the erasure (benefits from the fact that `std::set` and `std::unordered_set` iterator are not invalidated by addition or removal if the removal is not on there element).

But do not do this unless you need greater performances. Your code is simple and readable.